# If gravity was a push force, would the universe be entirely uniform?

Tags: gravity

Since gravity is a "pull" force, as it causes things to come together, the opposite would be a "push" force, where any matter would repel any other matter.  If this was the case, where gravity pushed instead of pulled, would this eventually cause all the matter in the universe to be equally space apart, and completely unmoving?  Or would the expansion of the universe have an effect on this, like in our universe (it's what stops gravity from bringing all matter into one single point)?

Comment: Where does the push force come from? Gravity is related to mass, what about this force?

Comment: I suppose we could ask if there's anything inherent in GR that requires the constant $G$ to be positive ?  A negative $G$, if possible (obviously just mathematically, not in our universe) might equate to what's being asked ?

Comment: I think this is too hypothetical for a good answer. The large-scale behaviour of the universe (_e.g._ expansion) is itself determined by gravitational forces, so it isn’t enough to just flip a sign in Newton’s law — you have modify general relativity. I don’t think you can meaningfully do this, just like you can’t really change the power 2 to anything else. (For example, I think you’d have to make sense of negative energy density.) “It's not that the mathematics gets easier as time passes, [...] but rather that the principles [...] have a greater sense of inevitability about them” (Weinberg)

Comment: Also, note that expansion is not the _only_ thing guarding us against collapse, nor even the main one: there’s Coulomb repulsion (for atoms, molecules, chairs), matter pressure (for Earth), radiation pressure (!—for stars), “degeneracy pressure” (for neutron stars), conservation of angular momentum (for solar systems, galaxies, galaxy clusters) and probably other stuff I’ve forgotten. It might also be that without expansion things would _eventually_ collapse—I’m not sure—but only after a very, very long time. Current age of the Universe kind of long.